# Create variable dynamically as much as other variable's length in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a questions app. The questions are not static and the answers are dynamic, they can be more than 4. For demo purposes, I have a dummy variable like this :

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'what is your personality?',
      'answers': [
        'Calm',
        'cheerful',
        'Romantic',
        'Sporty',
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What is your favorite color?',
      'answers': [
        'Blue',
        'Red',
        'Green',
        'Yellow',
        'White',
      ]
    },
  ];
```

Temporarily I'm storing the selected answer in the following variable :

```
List<String> selectedAnswer = [];
```

And when the following button is pressed, it can store its value to the variable.

```
children: List.generate(question['answers'].length, (index) {
  var selected = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedAnswer.length; i++) {
    if (selectedAnswer[i] == question['answers'][index]) {
      selected = true;
    }
  }
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => setState(() {
    if (selected) {
      selectedAnswer.remove(question['answers'][index]);
    } else {
      selectedAnswer.add(question['answers'][index]);
    }
  }),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            border: Border.all(color: primaryColor)),
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: (selected) ? primaryColor : Colors.transparent,
        )),
      ),
      SizedBox(width: Spacing.smallPadding),
      Text(question['answers'][index],
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline6!
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
    ],
  ),
),
```

And my real goal is to store the selected value of each question to its own variable. So that I can easily send it to an API, but the problem is that the question can be more than the above. Can it be done? if can't, then can you suggest me the best approach.

Tell me if there's anything you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear as to what the problem is, but if I understood correctly, you have an unknown number of questions, each with an unknown number of answers. You want to be able to create the relevant widgets for them and store the answer per question in a way that will be easy to extract later and pass to some API. Correct?

With that in mind, I would have a slightly different structure to hold the selected answers:

```dart
final Map<String, String> answers = {
  'What is your favorite color': 'Pink',
  'Who is your favorite person': 'Uncle Sam',
};

// Add an answer to the collection.
answers[questionId] = answerId;
```

In practice, I would do something like this:

```dart
// questionnaire_widget.dart
class Questionnaire extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext) {
    return Column(
      children: questions.entries.map((q) => Question(q)).toList();
    );
  }
}

// question_widget.dart
class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final QuestionModel question;

  @override
  build(BuildContext) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(question.questionText),
        question.answers.entries.map((answer) => Answer(
          question.questionId,
          answer,
        )).toList();
  }
}

// answer_widget.dart
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final AnswerModel answer;
  final String QuestionId;

  @override
  build(BuildContext) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text(answer.answerText),
      onPressed: () {
        // Store the answer in the answers collection.
        // For example: globalAnswersVariable[questionId] = answer;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

One thing to note is that you should probably use some state management here, instead of a global variable. For example, you could use [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod), which makes it easy to access Providers from any widget.

Also, I've added a hypothetical `questionId` to the data structure, as that is a more robust solution. (Image having to support more than one language. Or fixing a spelling mistake.) In general, you should rely on IDs, and not the actual values in your data structures.